# Three table join

Tags: sql

I have three tables.

One is with articles, one is with tags for the articles, and a table to link these tables because it's a many-to-many relationship. Each article has some tags, and to keep the tag table small and the data integer I need a table to link them together.

Now I have to search the tags for certain keywords, and select the articles who are linked to these tags. What's the most efficient way to this? Here's a visual presentation of the tables:

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Doesn't have to be _"the most efficient way"_, but a way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most efficient way to search articles/documents is **not** to use relational DB. That is not it's Forte. SOLR for example would be perfect for that.

But:

```
SELECT
   a.id
FROM
   article a
  join
   article_tags b
  on
   a.id = b.article_id
  join
   tags c
  on
   b.tag_id = c.id
where
  c.tag_name = {$cleaned_input_tag_name}
```

u can alos make `c.tag_name = {$cleaned_input_tag_name}`
a `IN` statement or `LIKE` statement